# Accessing pair elements in a set in C++

Tags: c++

I want to access the `first` and `second` elements of the pair that is included into a set in C++.
I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  set < pair<int, int> > pairTest;
  set < pair<int, int> >::iterator pairIt;

  for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
  {
    // inserting into the pair set
    pairTest.insert( {i, i*10} );
  }

  int m = pairTest.size();

  cout << "pairTest elements are: ";
  for (pairIt = pairTest.begin();pairIt!=pairTest.end();pairIt++)
  {
    // I have the problem in the following
    cout << *pairIt.first << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, apparently it's not the correct way to do, and I have been looking stackoverflow and other websites but still couldn't find an answer.
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you first access the `first` member and then try to dereference it (`.` takes precedence over `*`) and the `first` member is not a pointer so you can't dereference it. You have to do it the other way around and give explicit precedence by adding parentheses:

```
(*pairIt).first
```

Which in C++ has a nifty "shortcut operator" (which is exactly the same as the above code):

```
pairIt->first
```

Comment: A quick one,and hah,  usually operator precedence bites one's butt first time with & and !=

Comment: @Swift can you give an example?

Comment: @Abhinav Gauniyal e.g. `if( a & SOME_BIT_MASK != SOME_VALUE ) ...` does not compute well... because first comes !=

Comment: @Swift ah! Never been in that situation but I'll keep that in mind!